# Baseurl and url config didn't work for jekyll on github

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm new to jekyll and I'm trying to figure out how to make the config 'baseurl' and 'url' work on github

I set to config like this in `_config.xml`:

```
baseurl: /documentation

url: https://michaelpw.github.io/
```

However, when I open this page https://michaelpw.github.io/documentation/, it displayed the error 404 not found.

Anybody knows what went wrong? I tested on local and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Currently your site is being deployed to `https://michaelpw.github.io/`.

To have it at `https://michaelpw.github.io/documentation/`, you need to move the site to a **separate repository** named `documentation` instead of `michaelpw.github.io`.

Comment: Hi Marcanuy, thanks for your reply. I've created another repository under my account and put my site there but when I went to [link](https://michaelpw.github.io/documentation/), the page was still not found. Is there any other configurations needed?

Comment: @MikeNguyen Code is fine, something should be wrong in the configuration of Github pages, go to https://github.com/michaelpw/documentation/settings - Github pages section - **source** should be **Master branch**. If that not works post the error log of https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages/

Answer (score 2):

I think that the meaning of Base Url is not crystal clear. Please, [review this link](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/)

If you want to set up a base url, you need to create a new Jekyll site in Github -> [Follow these steps](https://24ways.org/2013/get-started-with-github-pages/)