# Github pages ignores Jekyll's baseurl for custom subdomain

Tags: github, jekyll, subdomain

My main Github repo uses my custom domain: `domain.com`.
Another Github repo uses my custom subdomain: `sub.domain.com`. However, I actually want to serve it to `sub.domain.com/subdirectory` instead.
I figured I would add `baseurl:/subdirectory` to my config.yml file, which works locally as it is correctly served at `localhost:4000/subdirectory` and everything works perfectly.
Problem is that it doesn't work in production. Github pages completely ignores the baseurl and keeps trying to serve it at `sub.domain.com`. All the relative links are then obviously broken since they're pointing to `sub.domain.com/subdirectory`.
How can I fix that?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Baseurl and url config didn't work for jekyll on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743494/baseurl-and-url-config-didnt-work-for-jekyll-on-github)

Comment: FWIW, I've got the same problem.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, the thread you link to addresses the case when you don't have a custom domain. OP has a custom domain.