# Baseurl and url in config doesn't work for Jekyll on Github

Tags: github, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743494/baseurl-and-url-config-didnt-work-for-jekyll-on-github), however I did exactly what the two solutions said to do. I still have the same 404 error.

For me I have https://enkrypton.moe/osb/ . When clicking links, it removes the `/osb/` from the link which causes 404. https://enkrypton.moe/scripts/ez-lyrics . This is the link I want, with `/osb/`, https://enkrypton.moe/osb/scripts/ez-lyrics

[Workflow](https://github.com/Enkrypton/osb/blob/main/.github/workflows/jekyll.yml) and [Config yml](https://github.com/Enkrypton/osb/blob/main/_config.yml)

A few links were removed because of Stackoverflow auto spam detection so if anyone can put those back it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you read what others said, you shouldn't configure `baseurl` at all, https://github.com/lextm/jekyll-theme-chirpy/blob/v5.4.0/_config.yml#L6 Did you try to set `url` to `https://enkrypton.moe/osb/`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up hardcoding my url into the .html files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The way I got inline images to work on Github Pages:

- In `config.yml`... (1) set the `url` field to just be the "base" of your URL. This URL should match the pattern `https://<your-github-username>.github.io` (2) set the `baseurl` field to be the name of your repository where this Github Pages repository is built from. This field must start with a forward slash, so `/<repository-name>`
- In your actual Markdown file, you'll cite the image in-line like this:

```markdown
![alt]({{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/filename.jpg)
```

[ source: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/master/docs/_posts/2010-08-05-post-image-standard.md ]